# CupertinoDialog cannot pop when Navigator.pop(context) is called together with a function using a global key

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-cupertino

Why can't CupertinoDialog pop when Navigator.pop(context) is called together with a function using a global key?

```
final GlobalKey <_PlayyButtonState>_playingButtonState = GlobalKey<_PlayyButtonState>();

...
Future<void> showAlert(){
    return showCupertinoDialog<void>(
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext context) => CupertinoAlertDialog(
        title: const Text('Re-write?'),
        content: const Text('Are you sure? You will have to write from scratch.'),
        actions: <CupertinoDialogAction>[
          CupertinoDialogAction(
            child: const Text('Re-write',
                style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.red
                )
            ),
            isDestructiveAction: true,
            onPressed: () {
              _playingButtonState.currentState._onToggle();
              Navigator.pop(context); <---- does not pop after calling the function above
            },
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Removing the code

```
      _playingButtonState.currentState._onToggle();
```

allow the CupertinoDialog to pop again

Answer (score 1):

Instead of this

```
 onPressed: () {
              _playingButtonState.currentState._onToggle();
              Navigator.pop(context); <---- does not pop after calling the function above
            },
```

Use this:

```
 onPressed: () {

Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 1000), () {
```

// Here you can write your code

```
 Navigator.pop(context);

});
              _playingButtonState.currentState._onToggle();
           
            },
```

Comment: Hi @Tasnuva, thanks for the reply. I realised there was a careless mistake somewhere in the code that kept calling cupertinodialog even after i closed it. I've just solved the issue.